# Define Flag in c, bitfield struct or macro set and get

Tags: c

I work with an old code in embedded app. I saw two different approaches to set flag bits:

1-

```
#define BIT_0       0x1
#define BIT_1       0x2
#define BIT_2       0x4
#define BIT_3       0x8
#define Curr        BIT_0
#define Ready       BIT_1
#define Sleep       BIT_2
#define Wait        BIT_3

#define SET_BIT(var,bits) ((var) |= (bits))
#define CLEAR_BIT(var,bits) ((var) &= (~(bits)))
```

2-

```
struct PROCESS_FLAG
{
unsigned long Curr          :1;
unsigned long Ready         :1;
unsigned long Sleep         :1;
unsigned long Wait          :1;
};

union STATE_FLAG_REG
{
    unsigned long       All;
    struct STATE_FLAG   bit; 
}
```

In the first i define macros to get and set flags, i can set any flag variable, like `unsigned long flag` and set with `SET_BIT(flag,3)`.

In the second, a define a struct of bitfield.

I have some question:

1. What is the best way in terms of saving memory?
2. What is the best way in terms of CPU usage?
3. What is more proper to define?

Note: if there is any another good approach i would be happy to learn more.

Comment: your examples have many subtle problems... they really should be fixed before asking those questions.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath please tell me where is the problems?

Comment: there is no need to use flags in your example. If you have only 1 flag activated, you can use a variable instead of 4 to store the state.

Comment: @SoftwareQustions: one-bit at a time interface, unnecessary `long`s, `3` hardcoded, wrong bit-field (1,2,3,4??)...

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant, its an sample example, i have more than 100 flags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the best way in terms of saving memory?

There is no difference: if you need the same number of bits inside a primitive, both approaches would result in using the same amount of memory. `struct` may use additional memory if you use more bits than fits in an `int`, though: if you need 40 bits on a 32-bit system, your `struct` may be larger than five bytes.

> What is the best way in terms of CPU usage?

There should be no difference there either: there's no magical way of setting the bits in a byte, so the compiler will make code that does the same thing as your macros.

> What is more proper to define?

Since bit fields do not give you control over the exact bits used by each component, only the first approach works when you must access bits inside hardware registers in special memory locations. In all other situations the decision is up to you, as a matter of coding style.

Answer (score 3):

> 1- What is the best way in terms of saving memory?

There is no single best way. It depends on your usage. If your requirement is to run on tight on memory system, you can use following ways (or explore different ways):

a. Check for structure padding and alignment and rearrange member for less size.
b. Use bit fielding wherever possible (as shown in the example).

Or you can rearchitect application to use less memory as possible.

> 2- What is the best way in terms of CPU usage?

I think by CPU usage it means less CPU cycle to read structure. For that, keep structure aligned with their natural boundary of padding. For 64-bit member, it must be aligned to 64-bit memory.

See structure padding and alignment more for details at http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structure-member-alignment-padding-and-data-packing/

> 3- What is more proper to define?

Whatever the way which is compiler independent or available on the all the compilers or at least in the compilers you are targeting.